# Javascript: add attribute in for ... in statement

Tags: javascript, attributes

When I use here the direct ".attribute" form in the inner for-loop (commented line) it doesn't work. How do I have to rewrite the commented line to get the direct ".attribute" form working?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult()
{
    var data = {
        menge : { type : 'number', value : 5, size : "40" },
        bezeichnung : { type : 'text', value : 'Kuchen', size : "80" },
        euro_stueck : { type : 'text', value : 13, size : "40" } };
    var table_id = "product";
    var table = document.getElementById( table_id );

    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName( 'tr' ).length;
    var tr = table.insertRow( rows );
    for ( name in data )
    {
        var td = document.createElement( 'td' );
        var input = document.createElement( 'input' );
        input.name = name;
        for ( attr in data[name] )
        {
            //input.attr = data[name][attr];  <---
            input.setAttribute( attr, data[name][attr] );
        }
        td.appendChild( input );
        tr.appendChild( td );
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="product">
    </table>
    <br />
    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="displayResult()" value="OK" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **[Works Fine](http://jsfiddle.net/3hpEY/)**

Comment: Isn't guaranteed to work fine, because calling `setAttribute` to set `value` sets the `defaultValue` instead of the current value property. Setting the `value` attribute *may* also set the current value in *some* cases and on *some* browsers, but it's not defined to and it's not reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you just need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), as you do elsewhere:

```
for (attr in data[name])
{
    input[attr] = data[name][attr]; // <---
    input.setAttribute( attr, data[name][attr] );
}
```